# imagesLoaded jquery function not working with masonry

Tags: jquery, html, tumblr, jquery-masonry

I've been working on this for some time.

I am trying to use a fadein function after all of my post content has been loaded and had the relevant masonry layout applied. Have researched this in several places, tried different versions of the [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) but cannot seem to get it working.

This is my basic html structure:

```
<div id="posts">

    <article class="post text clearfix">
    // text post etc
    </article>

</div>
```

I am calling masonry and then the imagesLoaded jquery plugin.

My js looks like this (I realise I need to set display:none in the css at some point).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $eachContainer = $('.post');
    $eachContainer.hide();
    var $wall = $('#posts');
    $wall.imagesLoaded( function() {    
        $eachContainer.fadeIn();
        $wall.masonry({
            columnwidth: 84,
            itemSelector : '.post'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I've tried running the above in a window.load function too. It seems as though with this function the masonry columnWidth is not being calculated.

I actually have two tumblrs where this code is being tested.

1. http://kidsofdada.tumblr.com/ (this is working but I want the images to fade in AFTER the masonry grid has been set.
2. http://childofdada.tumblr.com/ images fading in, but masonry border not setting properly, also not resizing when the browser is dragged.

EDIT 1:

I have tried to recode the above function using the example provided at the plugin site. So now my code looks like this:

```
 var container = document.querySelector('#posts');
 var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    columnWidth: 84,
    itemSelector: '.post',
    isInitLayout: false
});

msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function() {
    console.log('layout is complete');
    $('.post').fadeIn();
});
```

When the page is loaded all posts are hidden. How do I bind the function only to the window.load, or document.ready functions? 
If you resize the browser, this triggers and will display the posts: http://childofdada.tumblr.com/

EDIT 2:

Trying to implement the false flag code, I realise I may have this written incorrectly (have tried switching it).

```
var firstTime = 'false';

var container = document.querySelector('#posts');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    columnWidth: 84,
    itemSelector: '.post',
    isInitLayout: false
});

if (firstTime == 'false') {
    msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function() {
        console.log('layout is complete');
        $('.post').fadeIn();
        firstTime = 'true';
    });
}
```

Comment: Think you should use the masonry `layoutComplete` event instead.

Comment: Hmm, I am going to edit my question, because I think layout is firing every time the layout is altered (via resize for example). I need it to only run on the initial document load.

Comment: So worst case use a flag e.g. `var firstTime = false;` then set to true in `layoutComplete` and execute your code only when `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/nVYcP/

What i had to do is hide the body with `visibility: hidden`, and not `hide()` (which set `display: none`). This tricks jQuery/masonry to calculate the correct places.

After the `.masonry` you display it back by first hiding with the jQuery accepted method, removing the visibility tag, and showing with `fadeIn`. The time here have to be a bit big (i put 2 seconds) or else the animation is never visible due to the lag to fade in the large amount of itens.

The code to show the posts can be put in the `imagesLoaded` callback as well, but I think it's working fine this way.

Final code:

```
$('#posts').masonry({columnWidth: 84});

$("#site")
    .hide()
    .css("visibility", "")
    .fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I did try it in it's simplest form and it did seem to work, although I did get a FOUC initially, so I changed my css to hide the entire document. I will try and integrate it with the imagesLoaded function. I think because the 2 seconds is a hack (I guess) it was not working for me on the site, although 5 seconds did.

Comment: -- I think because the site is loading js, css and some images from several remote sources.

Comment: yes, 5 seconds should be best, it depends on the client computer power. let me know if it work for you.

Comment: Hi. I tried a few variants but it seems that layoutComplete is not trggered on window load, only after the browser is resized. Have a look and see: http://childofdada.tumblr.com/ I wonder if I need to tie it to the imagesLoaded function but that also appeared to give me issues.

Comment: Don't worry though I need a solution and If I cannot get it to work via the kind people on SO, I will have to post it as a small job on peopleperhour.com (I would like to understand it myself of course).

Comment: But why are you putting it inside layoutComplete ? If you do as I did on the fiddle it don't work ? Also, why you set isInitLayout=false ? That's why it isn't loading http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isinitlayout